# C# CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope using FileStream/XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, dispose, using, ca2000, ca2202

I have lots of code like this:

```
FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Temp\SNB-RSS.xml", FileMode.Open); 
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs)) 
{ 
   /* Some other code */
}
```

This gives me the following Code Analysis warning:

```
CA2000 : Microsoft.Reliability : In method 'SF_Tester.Run()', object 'fs' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'fs' before all references to it are out of scope.
```

If I follow the suggestion and I put the File.Open in a using statement, I get this:

```
CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage : Object 'fs' can be disposed more than once in method 'SF_Tester.Run()'. To avoid generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than one time on an object.: Lines: 39
```

I'm using VS2010 and I can't help but think I'm doing something wrong but I don't see it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI, "new XmlTextReader" has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create` instead, as Hans shows you below.

Comment: Jeepers...I didn't know the XmlTextReader had been deprecated.  This makes a lot more sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: The reason for `CA2202` is that disposing of a `Reader` or `Writer` also dispose of the `FileStream` used to create it; this means you have to dispose of `fs` if the construction of the `Writer` fails but not if it succeeds; that leads to [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3700444/562906) by **testalino**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sigh, exhausting isn't it.  Avoid all this by using the recommended Create() method:

```
 using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Temp\SNB-RSS.xml")) {
     //...
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

As nobody provided a solution that solves this issue yet, I'm writing my working solution down here:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite,    FileShare.ReadWrite);
try
{
   using (var fileWriter = new StreamWriter(fs, encoding))
   {
       fs = null;
       fileWriter.Write(content);
    }
 }
 finally
 {
     if (fs != null)
         fs.Dispose();
 }
```

This removes CA2000.

Comment: Ok, been searching all morning and this is the first approach that actually worked. Thanks! My issue was with StreamWriter not XMLReader but same CA Hell just the same.

Comment: Actually this is the best answer.
See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/611525/disposable-objects-and-ca2000-ca2202-warnings

Comment: **testalino**: You may wish to integrate this into your answer: The reason that `using fs` as in the question causes `CA2202` is that disposing of a `Reader` or `Writer` also dispose of the `FileStream` used to create it; this means you have to dispose of `fs` if the construction of the `Writer` fails but not if it succeeds! This seems to me a flaw in the design of these classes. I can’t say I like having to use your pattern, but I don’t see a better approach; writing wrapper classes seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am only guessing; don't have time to go through a full analysis now.

Suppose the `XmlTextReader` constructor 'takes ownership' of the stream passed in, and so disposing the `XmlTextReader` will also `Dispose` the underlying stream.  That would explain the behavior you see.  Perhaps `XmlTextReader` constructor can throw, and in that instance, the original warning about `fs` would make sense.  However, given that hypothesis, this code

```
        var fs = File.Open(@"C:\Temp\SNB-RSS.xml", FileMode.Open);
        XmlTextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader== null)
            {
                fs.Dispose();
            }
        }
        if (reader != null)
        {
            using (reader)
            {
                /* Some other code */
            }
        }
```

is, I think, correct, but still yields a spurious warning.  This smells like a nice example that demonstrates the limitations of static analysis tools.

As someone else said, there is another API to directly create the reader from the filename (`XmlReader.Create()`), which avoids all this (and shows how well-designed scenario-focused APIs are a good thing for a surprising variety of reasons).

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/535118/ca2000-and-ca2202-offer-contradictory-warnings

If you're using a StreamWriter rather than XmlTextReader (as in the solution above) you could use a similar method via the relevant constructor; e.g.

```
var sw = new StreamWriter("filename.txt");
```

or

```
var sw = new StreamWriter("filename.txt", /*append to file = */ false );
```

It is not clear from the documentation whether the first form of constructor will overwrite or append to a file.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700444/562906) answer, the only way to work around it correctly is to do [as recommended in CA2202](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22DO+NOT+DISPOSE+OBJECTS+MULTIPLE+TIMES%22%29;k%28VS.ERRORLIST%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) and use an outer try-finally block instead of an outer using block. Inside the inner using, set the outer IDisposable object to null to prevent it from being accessed once the inner using has finished.

Here's a generic wrapper that does it "correctly", i.e. works around the badly designed XmlReader (maybe it should not have taken ownership of the stream it receives? Not sure what the right way to do it would be)

**Disclaimer**: Not really tested

```
public static TResult SafeNestedUsing<TOuter, TInner, TResult>(Func<TOuter> createOuterDisposable, Func<TOuter, TInner> createInnerDisposable, Func<TInner, TResult> body)
        where TInner : IDisposable
        where TOuter : class, IDisposable
    {
        TOuter outer = null;
        try
        {
            outer = createOuterDisposable();
            using (var inner = createInnerDisposable(outer))
            {
                var result = body(inner);
                outer = null;
                return result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (null != outer)
            {
                outer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
SafeNestedUsing<MemoryStream, XmlReader, XmlDocument>(
    ()          => new MemoryStream(array),
    (memStream) => XmlReader.Create(memStream, xmlReaderSettings),
    (xmlReader) =>
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
        return xmlDoc;
    });
```

This *is* quite clunky, and you may argue that it's better to repeat the try/set null/finally pattern instead. But for a repeating pattern of nested usings I'd rather do it this way than repeat the full thing each time.

Answer (score 0):

just use 'using' for the filestream

```
 using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
// some codes here

}
```

Don't modify fs and don't use fs.close() inside using curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `using` statement also on the FileStream itself just like on the XmlTextReader.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(VS.71).aspx.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: The original question clearly says he tried this, and it yields a different warning.