# MemoryStream, XmlTextWriter and Warning 4 CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage

Tags: c#, xml, linq, dispose

The **Run Code Analysis** command in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate returns a warning when seeing a certain pattern with `MemoryStream` and `XmlTextWriter`.

This is the warning:

> Warning   7   CA2202 : Microsoft.Usage :
>   Object 'ms' can be disposed more than
>   once in method
>   'KinteWritePages.GetXPathDocument(DbConnection)'.
>   To avoid generating a
>   System.ObjectDisposedException you
>   should not call Dispose more than one
>   time on an object.: Lines:
>   421   C:\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Songhay.DataAccess.KinteWritePages\KinteWritePages.cs   421 Songhay.DataAccess.KinteWritePages

This is the form:

```
static XPathDocument GetXPathDocument(DbConnection connection)
{
    XPathDocument xpDoc = null;
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    try
    {
        using(XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            using(DbDataReader reader = CommonReader.GetReader(connection, Resources.KinteRssSql))
            {

                writer.WriteStartDocument();
                writer.WriteStartElement("data");

                do
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("item");
                        for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                        {
                            writer.WriteRaw(String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", reader.GetName(i), reader[i].ToString()));
                        }
                        writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    }

                } while(reader.NextResult());

                writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                writer.WriteEndDocument();

                writer.Flush();
                ms.Position = 0;

                xpDoc = new XPathDocument(ms);
            }
        }

    }
    finally
    {
        ms.Dispose();
    }

    return xpDoc;
}
```

The same kind of warning is produced for this form:

```
XPathDocument xpDoc = null;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        using(DbDataReader reader = CommonReader.GetReader(connection, Resources.KinteRssSql))
        {
            //...
        }
    }

}

return xpDoc;
```

By the way, the following form produces another warning:

```
XPathDocument xpDoc = null;
var ms = new MemoryStream();
using(XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    using(DbDataReader reader = CommonReader.GetReader(connection, Resources.KinteRssSql))
    {
        //...
    }
}

return xpDoc;
```

The above produces the warning:

> Warning   7   CA2000 :
>   Microsoft.Reliability : In method
>   'KinteWritePages.GetXPathDocument(DbConnection)',
>   object 'ms' is not disposed along all
>   exception paths. Call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object
>   'ms' before all references to it are
>   out of scope. C:\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\Songhay.DataAccess.KinteWritePages\KinteWritePages.cs   383 Songhay.DataAccess.KinteWritePages

In addition to the following, what are my options?:

- Supress warning CA2202.
- Supress warning CA2000 and hope that
  Microsoft is disposing of
  `MemoryStream` (because
  **Reflector** is not showing me the source code).
- Rewrite my legacy code to recognize
  the wonderful `XDocument` and LINQ to
  XML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# CA2000:Dispose objects before losing scope using FileStream/XmlTextReader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128446/c-ca2000dispose-objects-before-losing-scope-using-filestream-xmltextreader)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should never use `new XmlTextWriter()`. It has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Secondly, the assignment to `ms` should be in a using block:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I believe that the warning is correct. The `MemoryStream` could be disposed when the `XmlTextWriter` is disposed, then again in the "`finally`" block.

Comment: Something to note here: In later versions of .Net Framework,  XmlWriter.Create(stream) creates an object where XmlWriter.Settings.CloseOutput is 'false', and you do actually need to dispose of the MemoryStream separately.

The problem is that CA2202 is still raised even though Dispose() is only being called on the underlying stream precisely once. I just suppressed the warning and justified it as a false positive.

Comment: @russell that makes good sense. If you pass it an existing stream, then it belongs to you, and you know when to close it.

Answer (score 1):

If this were my code-base I'd suppress it. Code Analysis is there to warn you of potential problems and as long as you (and everyone else on your team, including all future devs) are aware of the potential problems you're fine. [Here's Microsoft's way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx) of avoiding the issue (which defeats the purpose of `using()` in my opinion.

On a similar note, [here's some code](http://chrishaas.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/cannot-access-a-closed-stream-with-memorystream-and-streamwriter/) that shows you how you might actually run into the bug that this fixes. The first code block writes to a `MemoryStream` closes the `StreamWriter` and then tries to read it in another `StreamReader`. Unfortunately `Dispose()` on the `StreamWriter` also closes the `MemoryStream`. The solution is to create the `StreamReader` from within the `StreamWriter`.